# tar: This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: tar

I split a huge folder:

```
$ tar cvpf - somedir | split -b 50000m
```

… and then I transferred the split files to another server and merged it:

```
$ cat x* > somedir.tar.gz
```

but when I tried to extract the file, it shows errors:

```
$ tar xvf somedir.tar.gz
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Archive contains obsolescent base-64 headers
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

How can I transfer/extract it to be folder again? thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. You have not compressed so do not name the target file `somedir.tar.gz` -- call it `somedir.tar`

   - this is not really relevant to your problem -- `tar xvf` should have worked nevertheless
2. Recheck your transfer (specifically if over FTP) is a binary one (and not a text transfer)
3. Finally do check that the files have actually transferred correctly

   - for this, you might check source and target side file sizes
   - or even better, match their MD5 sums on both sides (this will check point 2 also)

---

If you've checked the above points and the MD5 sums match on both ends, you should first try to check your split. So, does the join and tar-tf work on the source machine?

If your `somedir` is very large, try the work-flow with a small directory.
Use `tar cvpf` to get a simple tarball first, split and test after a rejoin.
Now, copy the split to your target machine as before and test after a rejoin there.
This should speed up locating your problem.

Comment: I check MD5 sums, it is ok

Comment: I would do the md5 sum before splitting and after catting.

Answer (score 1):

Don't name your concatenated tarball `somefile.tar.gz`, since it is **not** compressed. To avoid confusing `tar`'s compression auto-detection, you really do need to name it `somefile.tar`.

Quoting from the `tar` info manual:

> The format recognition algorithm is based on "signatures", a special
>   byte sequences [sic] in the beginning of file, that are specific for certain
>   compression formats.  If this approach fails, `tar' falls back to using
>   archive name suffix to determine its format ...

So, what's probably happening is that your tarball doesn't begin with any of the signatures of known compression methods, so `tar` falls back to using the filename to determine the compression. In your case, the name ends with `.gz`, so it assumes `gzip` compression. This leads to the errors you're getting, since the file is not actually compressed.

tl;dr: Name the tarball with the `.tar` suffix, not `.tar.gz`.

Comment: When `tar` cannot determine format based on the [sic] signatures in the file header, I've usually found the file to be corrupted -- naming with different extensions has never really helped. Getting the correct format archive has always helped.